# Grep -f and only return the first match

Tags: bash, csv, grep

I'm working with a large CSV that follows a basic process.

1. Backup the working original
2. Generate a skeleton CSV
3. Read from another CSV, format the contents, and then append it to the skeleton
4. Append the data from the backup to the new one.

The issue I'm running into is that when I read in the contents from the backup, I'm using `grep -Ev -f` with a file containing regexes to exclude undesired data from the backup to be included in the next revision. This currently presents a problem because grep appears to evaluate each regex in the file against every line from STDIN which will cause duplicates. The simple solution would be to simply pipe it through `sort | uniq` and call it a day but that will screw with the formatting of the csv currently in use. I can elaborate if needed but the short of it is I run a script to bulk process IP addresses but there is also manual editing of the file by other people and with the current form of the script the final output will be all of the automated content with manual entries being at the bottom of the file.

So, is there anyway without some ugly looping of grep to tell it to stop evaluating a line after a pattern is matched? Using `-m 1` will stop grep after the first match in the whole stream where I need it stop after each new line.

Comment: Can you show an example of such regexes and lines? I am not able to replicate the problem.

Comment: `^10\.*`

`^192\.168\.*`

etc... etc.. for RFC1918 as well as a couple random IP addresses that are unnecessary. The problem appears to be that it's evaluating  every line against every expression when what I want is for it to find a match and then stop using the expressions in the file.

Comment: Disregard everything. The list does only match for one expression. The test file I was using got changed inadvertently so I was seeing duplicate results. `grep -Ev -f $list_of_expressions` will produce my desired results.

Comment: @purblemcgallister post your comment as the answer to this question so that it does not appear as an unanswered question in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

For the task you want to accomplish. It would be best in my opinion to use AWK. You can find an excellent tutorial for AWK at : http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html. You basically need to change the input field separator for awk with

```
awk -f',' foo.awk bar.dat
```

As far as the problem with sorting is concerned follow this : http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-to-use-awk-to-sort-243177/